# Second redux store for elements dragged by user

Tags: redux, architecture, drag-and-drop

I know that to have multiple stores in one application is generally not good idea. But I want to know your opinion in this particular case.

I am creating diagram editing application. Currently I have in store nodes: `{id, x, y}` and link: `{from: idOfNode, to}` between nodes. And I dispatch action to update node position only on `dragEnd` event. This causes the visual bug because link between nodes is updated only on `dragEnd` and not while dragging as expected. The easy solution is update position of node on `dragMove` event but it creates lots of actions and because of that redux history is total mess.

So I am thinking about creating second store for purpose of those 'on move data'. Is it good case for using multiple stores? Or can you see other solution?
Thanks.

Comment: If something needs to appear visually while drawing, local component state seems to be a better solution (not sure if you're using a popular view rendering library here, so this would apply to React). Your idea would of course work, but that second redux store also has lots of actions fired and would be a "mess" in that sense. (the same line of arguing applies to the second store, it's still bad). Not persisting such volatile UI state in redux would be the better option imho.

Comment: @timotgl The problem with local component state is that I have more types of nodes so the state must be in the root component and I need to pass state and its update method to each component. This is also not very clean. An alternative would be use provider but that's kind of a simulating of the store. Although maybe the best alternative.

Comment: For rendering I am using Konvajs, but I don't think it can influence this decision at all.

Comment: In that case (still assuming we're talking about React here), a dedicated React context provider + consumer is the best pattern to use I think. Yes it's similar to the redux store because both are ways to manage global state, but it doesn't have the overhead of redux and the concerns are separateded, which is good.